# Ubuntu PDF reader/editor to fill advanced PDF forms

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf, forms

### Scenario

I have to fill a PDF form made with Adobe LiveCycle Designer that I suppose to contain some sort of scripts:

1. It connects to a remote server to check to be the latest version of the form
2. It has a button to check that mandatory fields have been filled

It also allows to somehow "attach" some files *in* the document itself.

If I try to open the file with Ubuntu's default PDF reader I get this message (that is never "replaced by the proper contents"):

[image: message]

The instructions say to use Adobe Reader "or an equivalent software".

### Question

I need a software that:

1. allows me to fill such a form in a "regular" way (workarounds like converting the document in an image is not an option as it would make it invalid for my purposes)
2. works in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (through Wine is acceptable but Ubuntu software would be preferred)
3. is FOSS (otherwise I might just install Adobe Reader)

I don't mind if it is "a bit" complicated, if it has a GUI or command-line interface and so on - it must just work.

Is there such a software (or a way to achieve the result with Ubuntu's default PDF reader - but I doubt)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two that work: One works in 85-90% of government XFA forms (at least from Canada). Here:

https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/ (Note: one I found few work in MS Windows version but not Ubuntu, weird, I've reported it and submitted a link to the sample)

and here is an particle on installing FoxIT Reader on Ubuntu 20 which I'm testing:

https://kifarunix.com/install-foxit-pdf-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I'll report back on test I find via Wine as well.